# Connecting socket.io client to https

Tags: https, socket.io, server, client

I'm trying to build a web chat application and want to connect my client to the socket.io server with https. 
Seems like everything's fine, but the client is not connecting after all..

Server Code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(3000,function(){
        console.log("Https server started on port 3000");
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("Client connected");
           /*....*/
});
```

Client code to connect to server:

```
$(function($){
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3000', {secure: true});
.....
});
```

It kind of doesn't run the code inside of $(function($)..
When I make it a http server it works just fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem..

So for http it was enough if you begin your script on the client with

```
$(function(){
....
});
```

But it wouldn't work with https.
I changed it to

```
jQuery(function($){
....
})(jQuery);
```

Pretty odd but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
var socket = io.connect('/', {secure: true});
```

**EDIT:** By default socket.io will try to establish a connection on the same host as webserver hosts web content, so no need to specifying host/protocol/port. The `/` states to connect to default namespace.

Comment: Please add your comment to your answer